# Fetch objectId from a User in parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i'm new to parse and i'm trying to fetch a user objectId, but whatever i cant seem to return the objectId. I can easily return the username. this is my query:

```
                 PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
                 [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
                 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {
                         if (objects.count) {
                             NSLog(@"%@", [objects lastObject]);

                         }
                }
            }];
```

This returns something like this:

```
<PFUser:9dcc65tsdr:(null)> {
    username = AEleQFdBx9jdtypfsQmLtzAvW;
}
```

How do i return the objectId which is between PFUser and (null)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object.objectId` like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
 [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         if (objects.count) {
             for (PFObject *object in objects){
                NSLog(@"Object ID: %@", object.objectId);
             }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this: `[[PFUser currentUser]objectId`] much faster and works much better because you don't have to run a whole PFQuery.